# How to uninstall scons?

Tags: python, macos, makefile, scons

I'm downloaded scons 2.3.0 with official site and install it command:

> python setup.py install --standard-lib

And i have question how to uninstall scons?

MacOS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library itself should be in `/usr/local/lib/scons`. Executables (scripts) in `/usr/local/bin/{scons,sconsign,scons-time,scons.bat}`. Scripts may be with version number, e.g. `scons-2.3.0`. Finaly docs in `/usr/local/man/man1`.

Also look for the egg file with:

```
$ find / -name "scons*.egg-info"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Windows? Python 3.5? How to do remove it once it is accidentally installed on wrong python? (scons do not work with Py3)

Comment: All the same - remove scons from `Lib/site-packages` and `Scripts`. Windows installer suggests to install Python into `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`.

Comment: Thanks, so manual removal from usual folders with do the trick. Luckily there is file installation list in the Python folder.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my answer is similar and could not be possible without the one from @twil but I found more locations to potentially clear up for.

---

So delete all files which are related to the python version your want to clean up.

On MacOS we have `locate` so let's use that.

Running `locate "egg-info/PKG-INFO" | grep -i scons` gives me 2 `miniconda` locations refering to Python 3. We do not have to clean those up by manually delete those. That is done by the conda way.

Running `locate "scons-" | grep -v miniconda` give me files in `/usr/local/bin/scons` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-`. You can [uninstall using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user) depending on your installation location.

To find more 'scons' I had to skip

```
locate "scons" \
  | grep -v miniconda \
  | grep -v "python2.7/site-packages" \
  | grep -v "/usr/local/bin/scons" \
  | grep -v "/Applications" \
  | grep -v "/Library" \
  | grep -v "/Users"
```

finds

```
/opt/X11/include/X11/extensions/dpmsconst.h
/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.7.1/share/zsh/functions/_scons
/usr/local/share/mime/text/x-scons.xml
/usr/local/share/zsh/functions/_scons
```

which you have to handpick yourself for deletion. Ie the zsh file I found was not a target.

#### Man pages

Man pages are located in `/usr/local/share/man`.

I cannot find man pages:

```
man scons
No manual entry for scons
```

My lesson is always [installing scons](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch01s02.html) using Conda (or pip --user) not to corrupt the default MacOS python version.