# there are two versions of jupyter_client in my conda env, how can I update the other one?

Tags: pip, jupyter, conda

I am trying to update my jupyter_client to 5.2.2 to run my new jupyter notebook. I did that using `conda update jupyter_client jupyter_core`, but it does not work after I updated them because I found out there are two versions of jupyter_client and jupyter_core. How can I update the two package in py36_0 or, how can I delete the package in py36_0 sot that jupyter can run in my pip installed jupyter_client and jupyter_core?

```
 conda list jupyter
>jupyter 1.0.0   <pip>
>jupyter-client 5.2.2 <pip>
>jupyter_console 5.2.0 <pip>
>jupyter-core 4.4.0 <pip>
>jupyter-client 5.1.0 py36_0
>jupyter-core 4.3.0 py36_0
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the pip installed version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user pip and conda are both package managers, and though can be used together, I think it better practice to only use one or the other if/when packages can be managed by either. I use conda by default, and move to pip only when I cannot get a package through conda.

Comment: @emmet02 when II uninstall pip package, 5.2.2 version jupyter_client will be uninstalled instead of py36_0 package

Answer (score 0):

After I check, conda so far does not have 5.2.2 jupyter_lient and jupyter_core 4.4. So uninstall all the jupyter_client and jupyter_core and reinstall the package using pip

Comment: Anaconda does have jupyter_client 5.2.2 - https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter_client but so long as you are only running a single version it should make debugging easier. Personally would rather stick with the benefits of conda for package management.

Comment: but when I use 'conda update' the latest model is 5.1.0 version, for some reason, do you know why?

Comment: You may have other dependency issues. Are you calling conda update correctly? i.e "conda update jupyter_client"? Perhaps you have other packages which are preventing you from updating jupyter? (try conda update --all to see what updates are available for your entire environment)