# pip install package with --user and without --user, now I want to uninstall package installed without --user

Tags: python, pip

First, I run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and later, I run

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

So, this is what I have now

```
$ which -a virtualenv
/Users/admin/.local/bin/virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

This is my default virtualenv

```
/Users/admin/.local/bin/virtualenv
```

Now I want to uninstall, this,

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

It removed /usr/local/bin/virtualenv, the system wide package.

The package I installed using --user flag, which cannot be uninstalled.

I just manually removed the folder.

See this thread.

[How to uninstall a package installed with pip install --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user)